# Error: lexical error in RQGIS R statistics QGIS integration

Tags: python, r, qgis

I am new to this forum and also new to the package RQGIS which I am trying to use in R.

I installed the latest QGIS, R, Rstudio versions and downloaded & installed the RQGIS library with all dependencies on Windows 10.

I followed the instructions of the vignette("install_guide", package = "RQGIS"). But i didn't got far because when I run:

```
vignette("install_guide", package = "RQGIS")
library("RQGIS")

set_env(root = "C:\\Programme\\QGIS 2.18\\")
find_algorithms(search_term = "([Pp]olygon)(centroid")
```

I get an error message:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   Traceback (most recent call las
                 (right here) ------^
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:\ANACON~1/Scripts/conda.exe" info --json' had   status 1 
2: running command '"C:\ANACON~1/Scripts/conda.exe" info --json' had status 1
```

traceback shows:

```
13: .Call(R_parse, txt, bigint_as_char)
12: parse_string(txt, bigint_as_char)
11: parseJSON(txt, bigint_as_char)
10: fromJSON_string(txt = txt, simplifyVector = simplifyVector, simplifyDataFrame = simplifyDataFrame, 
    simplifyMatrix = simplifyMatrix, flatten = flatten, ...)
9: fromJSON(conda_envs)
8: conda_list(conda = conda)
7: rbind(conda_envs, conda_list(conda = conda))
6: python_environment_versions()
5: py_discover_config(required_module, use_environment)
4: initialize_python(required_module, use_environment)
3: ensure_python_initialized()
2: py_capture_output(py_run_string("processing.alglist()"))
1: find_algorithms(search_term = "([Pp]olygon)(centroid")
```

the set_env detected the installation path:

```
$root
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.18"

$qgis_prefix_path
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.18\\apps\\qgis"

$python_plugins
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.18\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins"
```

but I have a version of Anaconda2 installed in a different folder. Is it possible that the PATH variable is set wrong? And if so what to change/add to the PATH?

thanks in advance for help!

Cheers,
Nils

Comment: I added `PYTHONPATH` with `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib` and `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs` in addition to the PATH `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27;C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages` but that did not solve the problem.


To get things working I just uninstalled ANACONDA but don't see that as final soulution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `open_app()` looks for Python binaries installed on your system, and will use the one shipped with QGIS (under Windows) while ignoring Anaconda installations. 
But there was one problem when **reticulate** was updated to v1.1 which was solved with https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/100. Since then it should be possible again to run **RQGIS** (in conjunction with **reticulate** >= v1.2) while having also installed Anaconda Python.